# How to display visual rows and cols in textarea using css

Tags: html, css

How to create visual `rows` and `columns` inside a `textarea`?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a textarea for this?  It looks like the wrong element for this purpose.

Comment: i have to create what you see in a pic? what do you recommend?

Comment: I would suggest using a `form` with a `table` inside of it and then text inputs inside of each `td`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not terribly different than the other solutions here, but it's looking to me like you are asking for `<input type="text" />` boxes on the left-hand side, and status text on the right-hand side. I agree with the others that the simplest way to create this is with a `<table>`. Here's an example that looks almost identical to your input:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="border">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" value="2245319951" /></td>
   <td>Checkout Failed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" /></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- More repeated rows -->
 </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div.border * { 
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
}

div.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 268px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
table {
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, table tr, table td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 125px;
}

table td:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

table input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 125px;
}
```

And here is a [CSSDesk Snippet](http://cssdesk.com/Q4tmh) which shows it in action. On my version of Chrome, it renders as:

[image: Example]

Comment: thanks for the solution... i found something u will be intrested in handsontable.com ..they have done all the work

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a `<form>` with a `<table>` inside of it. Then for each `<td>` you could put an `<input type = "text" />`. I've included a quick example below w/ some basic CSS styling (you would want to be much more specific w/ your CSS selects in your code though).

http://jsfiddle.net/GGWsj/3/

**index.html**

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**style.css**

```
form {
    width:300px;
    height:90px;
    overflow:auto;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
}

table td {
    border:1px solid #ddd;   
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

table tr:first-child td {
    border-top:none;
}

table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom:none;   
}

input[type="text"] {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can style the rows and columns like this. As suggested by cimmanon you might be using the wrong element here. Maybe try using a table with a `overflow-y: scroll` applied so you get the scroll.

**EDIT**

Example below:

```
<table style="overflow-y: scroll">
    <tr>
        <td>2245319951</td>
        <td>Checkout Failed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1234567890</td>
        <td>Checkout Succeeded</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can insert labels or inputs into the `<td>` elements if you so wish.

**EDIT #2**

I've now created a jsFiddle with the styled black surrounding border, grey inside borders and scrollbar. http://jsfiddle.net/UG6zL/